# get attributes from ionRangeSlider

Tags: javascript, ion-range-slider

I want get attributes from ionRangeSlider

```
<input num="<?php echo $fet_profiles["id"];?>" type="text" class="range"  value="<?php echo $fet_profiles["percent"]; ?>" name="range" />
```

I want get num

```
$(".range").ionRangeSlider({
    min: 25,
    max: 625,
    step: 1,
    prefix: "%",
    grid: true,
    onChange: function(data) {
        var val_percent = data.from;
        var id_prof = $(this).attr("num");
        alert(id_prof);
    }
});
```

this result show to me = > undefined !

Comment: within the "onChange" function, try console.dir(this) and console.dir($(this)) to see what variables they have in the developer console. It may help you work out how to access the variable you're interested in.

Comment: Object
block
:
false
decorate_both
:
true
disable
:
false
drag_interval
:
false
extra_classes
:
""
force_edges
:
false
from
:
100
from_fixed
:
false
from_max
:
null
from_min
:
null
from_shadow
:
false
grid
:
true
grid_margin
:
true
grid_num
:
4
grid_snap
:
false
hide_from_to
:
false
hide_min_max
:
false
input_values_separator
:
";"
keyboard
:
true
max
:
625
max_interval
:
0
max_postfix
:
""
min
:
25
min_interval
:
0
onChange
:
ƒ (data)
onFinish
:
null
onStart
:
null

Comment: try with console.dir(this) and console.dir($(this)) separately. Whichever one give you what you just wrote shows you which is the one you want to refer to. It seems to me that your id_prof should  = this.grid_num, or $(this).grid_num. But that's just a guess.

Comment: no $(this).grid_num not equal attr num

Comment: my problem in this => $(".range").ionRangeSlider

Comment: but i want this => $(".range") sorry for my english

Comment: I think I can help better if you include an example in https://jsfiddle.net/. Try to make one that doesn't use the php code (as you cannot use php in jsfiddle);

Comment: library not working in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o2015vo2/

Comment: can you include a screenshot of what your slider looks like normally please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qv6yrjrv/1015/ working

Comment: great! So what would you like to know when you change the value?

Comment: i want get id_prof

Comment: I mean, what do you want id_prof to be? In general terms, what are you trying to do?

Comment: ok i have another more than input have id=ex+"id_prof" so i want change all this inputs when change slider but first i want get id_prof

Comment: id_prof isn't working because  $(this).attr("num") is undefined. I'm afraid I'm not understanding - would you be able to change you fiddle to include everything relevant?

Comment: That's all I have to explain

Comment: but thank you very much  @AnthonyHaffey For your help

Comment: can you say what id_prof stands for? Is prof short for some other word?

Comment: now i get the solution thx @AnthonyHaffey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is first add function have variable ex :

```
    function get_id(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

and we can add onchange in input ex :

```
<input  onChange="get_id(10)" type="text" class="range"  value="100" name="range" />
```

Working I want give thx for this good person to help me @AnthonyHaffey and sorry if my english is bad thx for all ^_^